# WPF window with WindowChrome resizing issue

Tags: c#, wpf

Have this simple XAML for a custom window. It works fine except during a resize (from the left, top, top-left and bottom-left) it looks awful. The window flashes like crazy. Doesn't seem like an OS issue as Microsoft's glass Windows app resize smooth as butter.

I'm trying to customize the window frame, but unless I use WindowChrome, I lose all the resizing, dragging, etc.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        WindowStyle="None"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="600">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="1,1,1,1" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Content="Test" Height="25" Width="75" />
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to customize the window frame, but unless I use WindowChrome, I lose all the resizing, dragging, etc.".* You could implement the resizing and dragging functionality yourself for a fully custom experience: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/